# How to store a table data in a variable that won't be wiped

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

so i have an if statement as follows

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

MySqlCommand select = new MySqlCommand("SELECT personID, address_addressID from person WHERE email='" + emailAddress + "' and password = '" + passwordR + "'", connect); //brings back the person ID if user details are correct            
using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(select))
    {
        adapter.Fill(table);

        string sessionVar = table.Rows[0]["personID"].ToString();
        Session["personID"] = sessionVar;

        int sessionVarAddress = Int32.Parse(table.Rows[0]["address_addressID"].ToString());
        Session["address_addressId"] = sessionVarAddress;
```

I want to be able to use the variable 'sessionVar' outside of the if statement, is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a variable outside a code block, you have to declare it outside:

```
string sessionVar;
using (...)
{
    sessionVar = table.Rows[0]["personID"].ToString();
}
```

You might run in trouble when it is an `if`, `foreach`, `while`, etc. block for example. It isn't guaranteed that the variable will be set. You have to set a default then, or assign a value in an `else` branch for example.

So not like this:

```
string sessionVar;
if (...)
{
    sessionVar = table.Rows[0]["personID"].ToString();
}

// using sessionVar here will yield a compiler error.
```

But like this:

```
string sessionVar;
if (...)
{
    sessionVar = table.Rows[0]["personID"].ToString();
}
else
{
    sessionVar = null;
}

// using sessionVar is allowed now.
```

Comment: thank's that's great, will I have a similar issue within a 'using' statement also?

Comment: You are using a `using` block. There it is guaranteed `sessionVar` will have a value (or an exception is throws, which skips the code following).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it isn't an if.

Anyway, you can do it this way:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
string sessionVar = "";

MySqlCommand select = new MySqlCommand("SELECT personID, address_addressID from person WHERE email='" + emailAddress + "' and password = '" + passwordR + "'", connect); //brings back the person ID if user details are correct            
using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(select))
    {
        adapter.Fill(table);

        sessionVar = table.Rows[0]["personID"].ToString();
        Session["personID"] = sessionVar;

        int sessionVarAddress = Int32.Parse(table.Rows[0]["address_addressID"].ToString());
        Session["address_addressId"] = sessionVarAddress;
```

You must initialize it with a blank string "" or it wont be compiled!

Comment: *You must initialize it with a blank string "" or it wont be compiled!* No, that is not true.

Comment: So i suppose my compiler is a bad person

Comment: No, a `using` statement is always deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

You can get sessionVar value, if you declare outside of the using.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
string sessionVar = "";

MySqlCommand select = new MySqlCommand("SELECT personID, address_addressID from person WHERE email='" + emailAddress + "' and password = '" + passwordR + "'", connect); //brings back the person ID if user details are correct            
using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(select))
    {
        adapter.Fill(table);

        sessionVar = table.Rows[0]["personID"].ToString();
        Session["personID"] = sessionVar;

        int sessionVarAddress = Int32.Parse(table.Rows[0]["address_addressID"].ToString());
        Session["address_addressId"] = sessionVarAddress;
}
```

Now you can access sessionVar value.

Comment: What's the sense in reposting my answer?

Comment: It isn't your answer, it is a similar answer. And if we are nitpicking, you posted a similar answer like mine too, which was here first... @MarcoSalerno

Comment: it's my same answer. and we posted together, he posted mins after ^^

Comment: Here, i have declared "sessionVar" variable from outside of using statement. Kindly have a look

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question but you can initialize the variable before the if statement like:

```
string sessionVar = "";
if(condition){
...
sessionVar = table.Rows[0]["personID"].ToString();
...
}
//Use the variable after the 'if' statement.
var newString =  sessionVar;
```